# Drive 4wire stepper motor with PWM type CNC controler

Tags: pwm, stepper-motor

How can I drive a stepper motor using PWM technique controller, since the stepper motor has 4 wires at 24v?

I want a confirmation.

Comment: How many half-bridges does this "pwm techniq controller" supply? Please add its data sheet to the question otherwise nobody can answer. If it's a simple half bridge or full bridge the answer is, it can't. Also confirm the wiring of the stepper : it could be simply 2 coils, or it could be 3 phases + Neutral (Y wound)

Comment: Please add the data sheet of the stepper motor as well as the PWM controller that you are using.

Comment: If the parts are suitable to be used together, by following their instructions.  If they are not compatible, you don't.  Product *usage* questions are not on topic here.